# IServiceCollection Configure method analog in .net Framework

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, autofac, .net-framework-version

I have an Interface - ITestClient, and I have an implementation - TestClient, config file - TestClientConfig.
And there are 2 projects on **.net core 3.1** and on **.net framework 4.7.**
Implementation on core:

Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
     (...)
     services.AddRestApiClient(Configuration)
     (...)
  }
```

Extensions.cs:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddRestApiClient(
    this IServiceCollection services,
    IConfiguration configuration,
    string section = "Endpoints:TestRestApi")
   {
     services
      .Configure<TestClientConfig>(configuration.GetSection(section))
      .AddTransient<ITestClient, TestClient>();

     return services;
   }
```

TestClient.cs:

```
public class TestClient : TestClient
    {
        (...)
        /// <summary>
        /// ctor
        /// </summary>
        
        public TestClient(IOptions<TestClientConfig> option)
        {
            if (_httpClient != null)
                return;

            _httpClient = new HttpClient();
            _httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(option.Value.Host);
            ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = int.MaxValue;
        }
```

I need to make the same implementation on the framework 4.7 via Autofac.
I register my entities in autofac:

```
builder.Register((c, p) =>
    new TestClient(p.Named<IOptions<TestClientConfig>>("option")))
    .As<ITestClient>();
```

but how do i set the configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix Autofac config:

```
builder.RegisterType<TestClient>().As<ITestClient>().InstancePerRequest();

builder.Register(ctx => new TestClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiHost"]))
.As<ITestClient>()
.InstancePerRequest();
```